# Why does my Prolog program repeat matches for the same thing when I press semicolon?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to match things in compound terms.

This is my term:

```
program(
    [
        argument(int, source_account),
        argument(int, destination_account),
        argument(int, amount)
    ], [
        change(source_account, amount),
        change(destination_account, amount) 
    ]).
```

I am trying to match the use of the arguments source_account and destination_account in the function term together into a list.

Currently `interception_between(X, Y, Z)` returns:

```
?- interception_between(X, Y, Z).
"Found fact no more body"
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [],
Z = [problem(change(_A))] ;
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [_B],
Z = [_B, problem(change(_A))] ;
```

But I think I should get:

```
 X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
    Y = [_B],
    Z = [problem(change(_B)), problem(change(_A))] ;
```

Due to the change(source_account, _) and change(destination_account)

Could you tell me What am I doing wrong?

When I press semicolon, I get this effect and I'm not sure why:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.4.2)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- interception_between(X, Y, Z).
"Found fact no more body"
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [],
Z = [problem(change(_A))] ;
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [_B],
Z = [_B, problem(change(_A))] ;
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [_B, _C],
Z = [_B, _C, problem(change(_A))] ;
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [_B, _C, _D],
Z = [_B, _C, _D, problem(change(_A))] ;
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [_B, _C, _D, _E],
Z = [_B, _C, _D, _E, problem(change(_A))] ;
X = program([argument(_, _A)|_], [change(_A, _)]),
Y = [_B, _C, _D, _E, _F],
Z = [_B, _C, _D, _E, _F, problem(change(_A))]
```

this is my code:

```
program(
    [
        argument(int, source_account),
        argument(int, destination_account),
        argument(int, amount)
    ], [
        change(source_account, amount),
        change(destination_account, amount) 
    ]).

interception_between(
    program(
                [argument(_, ARGUMENT_VALUE)|_], 
                [change(ARGUMENT_VALUE, _)|[]]),
        FACTS, NEW_FACTS1) :- 
    print("Found fact no more body"),
    append(FACTS, [problem(change(ARGUMENT_VALUE))], NEW_FACTS1).    
interception_between(
    program([argument(_, ARGUMENT_VALUE)|ARGUMENT_LIST], 
                [change(ARGUMENT_VALUE, _)|BODY_LIST]
            )
        , FACTS, NEW_FACTS2) :- 
    print("Found fact, calling recursively"),
    append(FACTS, [problem(change(ARGUMENT_VALUE))], NEW_FACTS1),
    interception_between(
        program(
                    ARGUMENT_LIST, 
                    BODY_LIST
                )
            , NEW_FACTS1, NEW_FACTS2).
interception_between(
    program( [], []), [], _).
interception_between(
    program( _, []), [], _).
```

Comment: Would you mind reducing the size of this program?

Comment: Thanks for your interest and comment and reply. I've shortened the code and outputs. The compound term and code for interception_between has the bare minimum to show the problem.

Comment: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 0):

A clue is in this behaviour in the output:

```
Y = [],
Y = [_B],
Y = [_B, _C],
Y = [_B, _C, _D],
Y = [_B, _C, _D, _E],
Y = [_B, _C, _D, _E, _F],
```

That pattern is the behaviour of backtracking over an unbounded list length:

```
?- length(Whatever, _).
Whatever = [] ;
Whatever = [_] ;
Whatever = [_, _] ;
Whatever = [_, _, _] ;
Whatever = [_, _, _, _] .
```

It's also a behaviour that can come out of `append/3` when the first argument is not bounded length:

```
?- append(Y, [3], _Z).   % only showing part of the output here:
Y = [],
Y = [_A],
Y = [_A, _B],
Y = [_A, _B, _C],
Y = [_A, _B, _C, _D],
Y = [_A, _B, _C, _D, _E],
Y = [_A, _B, _C, _D, _E, _F],
```

And it looks like your `?- interception_between(X, Y, Z).` puts an unbound Y as `FACTS` and then `append(FACTS, ...` starts generating increasing lengths of that on backtracking.

I don't understand what the code is trying to achieve to suggest what to do about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I have two lists Y and Z in interception_between(X, Y, Z) so that I can append, I don't think you can append a list to itself in Prolog. You need to produce a new list. I am trying to return [problem(change(source_account)), problem(change(destination_account))] from interception_between(X, Y, Z)

Comment: @SamuelSquire calling `interception_between(X, Y, Z)` looks like Y isn't a list but an unbound variable being made a list using append(), which makes ever-longer lists on backtracking. You can append a list to itself, if it's helpful - `?- X = [1], append(X, X, XX).` works and gives `XX = [1, 1].`. I don't understand what you are trying to return - what does it mean to intersect between 'programs' of 'accounts' with 'problems' and 'changes', and lists of 'facts'? Or to "match the use of arguments ... together into a list"? The code and description without context are too confusing.

Comment: I'm working on trying to do static analysis on abstract syntax trees. I am trying to identify usages of variables in a program.
My program has three arguments defined this is a bit like a function declaration. I am trying to match up where the argument is defined with where it is used in the function body. Which is the second argument in `program(arguments, body)`. `change` represents a variable assignment, i am trying to find where there is a `argument(int, X)` there is a matching `change(_, X)`. This is all usages of `X` and they are collected into `facts`